# How can I compute the most general unifier for these two expressions?

Tags: first-order-logic, unification

I have the following first order logic expressions:

$f(g(a, h(b)), g(x, y)),~f(g(z,y), g(y, y))$

and I want to compute the most general unifier for them. If I follow the algorithm found on [these slides](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sheila/384/w11/Lectures/csc384w11-KR-tutorial.pdf) then I get the following.

\begin{align*}
S_0 &= \{f(g(a, h(b)), g(x, y)), f(g(z,y), g(y, y))\}\\
D_0 &= \{g(a, h(b)),g(z,y)\}                    &[\text{first disagreement set}]\\
&\text{(need to unify these two functions)}\\
D_0'&= \{a,z\}                                  &[\text{first sub-disagreement set}]\\
\sigma &= \{z=a\}\\
D_0''&=\{h(b),y\}                               &[\text{second sub-disagreement set}]\\
\sigma &= \{z=a, y=h(b)\}\\
S_1 &= \{f(g(a, h(b)), g(x, h(b))), f(g(a,h(b)), g(h(b), h(b)))\}\\
D_0 &= \{x,h(b)\}                    &[\text{second disagreement set}]\\
\sigma &= \{z=a,y=h(b),x=h(b)\}\\
S_2 &= \{f(g(a, h(b)), g(h(b), h(b))), f(g(a,h(b)), g(h(b), h(b)))\}
\end{align*}
No disagreement, unifier found! $\sigma = \{z=a,y=h(b),x=h(b)\}$.

However, this is not the most general unifier as we have $\{y=h(b),x=h(b)\}\in \sigma$, so i think the MGU should actually be $\sigma' = \{z=a,y=h(b),x=y\}$.

Is this correct? When I use Prolog to unify them, it gives $\sigma'$. What did I do wrong in my following of the algorithm, so that it gave me a unifier that wasn't the most general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a small confusion with the notation. Notice that
$\sigma = \{z = a, \ y = h(b), \ x = h(b) \}$ and $\sigma' = \{z = a, \ y = h(b), \ x = y \}$ are the same unifier, written in a different way. It doesn't matter if we write $x = y$ or $x = h(b)$, since we also have $y = h(b)$. Hence, you did nothing wrong and you have computed the most general unifier.